# Can't multiply sequence by non-int type file for 2 by 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

```
    import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values=open('Q_wk10_data.txt','r')
valuesx=[]
valuesy=[]
for row in values:
    valuesx.append(int(row))
for row2 in valuesx:
    valuesy.append(int(row2)**2)
plt.plot(valuesx,valuesy)
plt.xlabel="x"
plt.ylabel="y"
plt.show()

X=np.array([[valuesx,valuesy],[10,10]])
theta=(-10*math.pi)/180
M=np.array([[math.cos(theta),-math.sin(theta)],[math.sin(theta),math.cos(theta)]])
XM=np.dot(X,M)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ads/Downloads/PRACT/qwk10.py", line 20, in <module>
    XM=np.dot(X,M)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I already converted my array containing the lists valuesx and valuesy to integers but I cant do dot product with my other array created.

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: What are you valuesx and valuesy variable?

Comment: valuesx and valuesy are [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]

Comment: Your `X` has a somewhat strange shape: `array([[list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), list([1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100])], [10, 10]], dtype=object)`. Is it what you wanted? You cannot multiply it by M.

Comment: Create a (2, N) array, X, that contains x and y values. (N represents the number of values of x in the file, Q_wk10_data.txt.)
 Create another (2, 2) array to contain the following matrix:
M=[■(cos⁡(θ)&-sin⁡(θ)@sin⁡(θ)&cos⁡(θ) )] where θ is (-10π)/180 radians. (M is called rotation matrix.)
Perform the multiplication of the array X by the array M. This will result into another (2, N) array, say X_r (i.e. X_r=MX). Plot the values in the second row of this new array against the values in the first row in the same figure as in Part (c) above. These are the questions how could i do it

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code by what I have understood from the question. This line `X=np.array([[valuesx,valuesy],[10,10]])` is in error because it changes the shape of the matrix `X` to `[3, N]` which is not expected. Following is the code that needed changing:

```py
X = np.array([np.array(valuesx), np.array(valuesy)])
XM = np.dot(X, M)
```